# Are there still coroutines in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, yield, coroutine

There is a detailed explanation of coroutines in Python 2 here http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/. However, searching Python 3 [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) for keywords "coroutine" and "(yield)" I find only asyncio.coroutines which are specific to asyncio module and they use "yield from" syntax.

Comment: Here are some links to documentation of yield and generators: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#yield https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380

Comment: Thanks, but still there is no even a word about coroutines there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Everything Beazley wrote continues to apply to Python 3.

Note. In the 2.7 *yield statement* doc, 'coroutine' only appears in the See also PEP 0342 title. For 3.x, the See also section, with that link, was moved to the *yield expression* section in the [previous chapter](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions).  The 3.x [yield statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#yield) doc has `(yield <expr>)` rather than just `(yield)`.

Comment: Thanks, now I see detailed official explanation of coroutines in [PEP 342](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/). As far as I understood, generators (which produce values) use "yield x" syntax, while coroutines (which consume values) use "x = yield" syntax. In Python 2 they used "x = (yield)" syntax, in Python 3 either "x = yield" and "x = (yield)" is possible. It would also be great if somebody provided most common uses of coroutines in python? Beazley talks about using them as pipelines and simple state machines...

Comment: The only use of coroutines in the stdlib is in asyncio, using the new yield from syntax.  Beazley did a new talk in 2014 that includes this.